# How to build an external C++ library to use with R/Rcpp (e.g. Boost)

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I can't seem to find anything on the internet which show you how to build and compile a C++ library such that it can be used in R via the Rcpp package. I am missing some steps where the library is somehow linked to R tools

For instance how do you get the boost library working with R or any other such library?

Normal instructions:

https://andres.jaimes.net/718/how-to-install-the-c-boost-libraries-on-windows/
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-from-the-command-prompt

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/index.html

Comment: @Roland The BH package doesnt include all the headers such as regex ect. Also might want to do this for a different package.

It would be nice to have some sort of general advice somewhere for people trying to do this

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416

Answer (score 0):

This is almost surely a duplicate but I am in-between tasks and cannot search now...

"It's still complicated" but Rcpp 1.0.5 now also ship this [arXiv paper I wrote on this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416) as this [vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf).  In short, you need to differentiate between

- header-only you can ship or include
- small-ish library you include and build
- an external library

The third one is hardest as you now have the problem of getting it to CRAN and your users.

Comment: Maybe my question was not quite phrased correctly.

Often in C++ you have to include headers

e.g. #include <boost/regex.hpp>

If you create a Rcpp function/C++ script and try to use one of these functions from the library, it will not work as it will not be able to find the function.

@Dirk Eddelbuettel  I think it has to be linked to R tools/ compiled with R tools?

There isn't any instructions for this out there that I can find

Comment: That is a more elementary error in that _even some "mostly-header-only" libraries such as Boost have _components_ that *require* linking.  We show that on the Rcpp Galltery, and have for years.  So your claim of "couldn't anything about this on the internet" still rings a wee bit hollow.

Comment: It also helps to differentiate between _compiler errors_ and _linker errors_. Not the same thing.

Comment: I think the issue is trying to understand what is going on here

Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="C:\MinGW\lib\libboost_regex.a")

I have built boost through the command prompt but I don't know what this is looking for "C:\MinGW\lib\libboost_regex.a"

How does one get to this point?